# Why is onready event fired when my cordova/phonegap app resumes from a plugin activity?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

Simple camera app using cordova-plugin-camera but the exact same behavior happens when using cordova-plugin-barcodescanner and when using phonegap instead of cordova directly:

js/index.js

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        alert('init');
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', app.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        alert('deviceready');
    }
};
app.initialize();

function capturePhoto(){
    navigator.camera.getPicture(
      function(data) { alert('success'); }, function(error) { alert(error); },
      {sourceType:1, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI}
    );
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
    <button id="shoot" onclick="capturePhoto();">Take photo</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now my base problem is that while the camera activity works completely fine, the photo I save from the plugin is not returned to the app - in fact, neither navigator.camera.getPicture's error nor success callbacks are invoked. Instead, my app is reloaded (though the activity is NOT destroyed) and thus the html page is reloaded, my app.initialize() function is called and the events are rebound. This means I have no way to access the result of the plugin I use. Furthermore because the main activity is not actually destroyed, but still active in the background, the techniques described here do not work: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html#lifecycle-guide

Why is the `deviceready` event being called when resuming from an android plugin?

Answer (score 2):

Figured out what's happening. Because I put the button inside a form, I guess even though it's not a submit button it submits the form, which is reloading the page. The solution was to remove the `<form>` tags.